# How to scan a column of data from a .tsv file and print headers based on total amount of numbers

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to scan a column of data in biomolecules which contains values from 1-12, and I'd like to create headers in my .tsv file based on the highest amount of numbers in the column. "1-generated, 1-chain, 2-generated, 2-chain ... up tp 12 in this case. "

[image: example]

I'm not sure how to do this so it automates creating the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep='\t') # load tsv as pandas dataframe
df['BIOMOLECULES'] = df['BIOMOLECULES'].str.split(',') # make list of string

total_numbers = df['BIOMOLECULES'].apply(len).max() # get highest number count in column
generated_headers = [str(i) + '-generated' for i in range(1, total_numbers + 1)] # dynamically create headings
chains_headers = [str(i) + '-chains' for i in range(1, total_numbers + 1)]
all_headers = ['FILENAME', 'BIOMOLECULES'] + [x for y in zip(generated_headers, chains_headers) for x in y] # combine all column headings in one list

df = df.reindex(columns=all_headers) # reindex to add empty columns
df.to_csv('filename.tsv', sep='\t') # save file
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how I can print data to these headers?